# Php efficiently mark messages as read

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, messaging

I have a messaging system (PHP/MYSQL) and I already prepared the field for read/unread in the simple message table

```
Table
- msgbody
- datetime
- receipent
- read/unread
- sent/unsent (this field is for sending of notification)
```

I have 2 questions

1. I understand when user create the message I will insert into the table with the field as Unread, and when I retrieve the message the first time with the following statement

   ```
    MYSQL statement: Select * from table WHERE receipient = "a";
   ```

What I do is I go through the array and then I set the unread field to read using multiple insert statements (very inefficient!)

Is there anyway I can forgo the array loop and update the field when I am selecting it?

And is this the correct way to determine whether a message is read?

2) I'm using jquery as my front end, and I can do ajax call to php, but I'm still curious how do I do I determine on the front end whether the user loaded and seen the message or not.

Anyone can shed some light on how should it be done?

- Ajax call to update to read when Ajax call to load is successful?
- Ajax call to update when database is read?
- Ajax call to update ......when?

**UPDATE: Added codes.**
My php code for INSERTING of message

**Disclaimer**: Codes are working fine. it's the process that I need help with.

```
$query = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO table (msgbody,date time,recipient,read,sent) VALUES(:msg,:date,:user,:read,:sent);
if ($query->execute(array(
':msg' => $msg,
':date' => $datetime,
':user' => $user,
':read' => '0',
':sent' => '0'))) {
return TRUE;
}


My php code for retrieving of message

$query = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE recipient = :user);
if ($query->execute(array(
':user' => $user
))){

$data = $query->fetchAll();

foreach ($data as $msg) {
if $msg['read'] == '0';
$this->updateRead($msg['id']);


}
```

$this->updateRead function includes updating table read field to 1, as well as sending Pusher to the original recipient so they know the message is read.

So what happen is if i have 1000 messages I may end up looping 1000 times just to mark 2-3 messages as Read.

Comment: Your table structure does not look good.

Comment: No, there's no way to combine a `SELECT` with `UPDATE` in a single query.

Comment: But sounds like a perfect situation for a Prepare once and Execute many

Comment: @madalinivascu If you mean joining the update with a select subquery, yes, but that doesn't return the selected data so it's not useful for this.

Comment: sorry I was adding the codes, and it's on now.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes the table is simplified. There's foreign key to sender and recipient etc, but my focus is on the read/unread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do the select and update in a single query. But you don't need a loop, you can update all the messages with a single query.

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE recipient = 'a';
UPDATE table SET read = 1 WHERE recipient = 'a';
COMMIT;
```

If you do these in a transaction, you don't have to worry about new messages being added between the two queries. Transaction atomicity should ensure that they see the same view of the database.

Comment: I tried this but I did face the problem when the messages are being sent too fast so updating and inserting end up updating the messages being inserted too. I'm do not understand what u mean by transaction atomicity. So i am thinking I should set it as Read as I am retrieving it. But not the other data that I have not retrieved, at that moment.

Comment: Transaction atomicity means that when you're doing queries inside a transaction, changes to the database made by other processes are not visible to you.

Comment: OH yes by the way I also remembered why this doesn't work because I also need to push the message to the original sender, and update their interface with the READ status.

Comment: I've simply changed my entire logic and doesn't require mass updating any more, and only change status to 'read' when individual message is being requested, which then I will select and update the status at the same time. But your answer is definitely correct!